# Linux Mint startup error due to insufficient disk space

Tags: linux-mint, disk-usage

I am on Linux Mint 18.3. I use it for JavaScript development. I have just Chrome, node and Visual Studio Code.

Just couple days ago disk analyzer told me, that there is not enough of disk space. I tried to delete (permanently) files, but free space wasn't updated. On my last successful startup I got lots of errors, that I couldn't even load any application due to insufficient memory space on the hard drive. Now I even couldn't enter into the system - after an successful login attempt, I am redirected again to the login form. Guest option gives the same result. All of recovery options I launched.

Updates:

Exactly that I need are just files from Linux, so I used Windows tools like Ext2 Volume Manager and Disk Internals. There is a problem as well.

1. With Ext2 I can mount disk but couldn't open
2. With Disk Internals I cannot copy home cause it's encrypted.

Also a decision can be to delete some files from Linux, maybe I can start a system later.

Comment: **My solution.** The problem was about insufficient disk memory space. I dont know why file system was crashed, but after an obvious decision to use Live USB like a way to launch `fsck`, I checked the broken partition manually, and then deleted installed libraries from /etc, in my case, npm and global packages. Then, it was possible to run a system in a normal mode, and clean other files from user home folder. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
fsck /dev/sda5
```

as advised by error message?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It's a perfectly valid approach.

Answer (score 0):

From the login form, press Ctrl+Alt+F2 and login without a graphical interface. Use the terminal commands to remove files from the partition that is full and reboot.

```
rm -r folder_you_dont_need
df -h
```

The last command will tell you how much space your partitions have.

Comment: Morning!

I found an answer to clean my cache inside /var/cache/archive *.deb files
But my /var/cache contains only folder /fontconfig and /ldconfig

After I am running recovery mode in Mint, its shows me first error after this:

Comment: `Begin: Will now check root file system ... fsck from util-linux 2.27.1
[/sbin/fsck.ext4 (1) -- /dev/sda5] fsck.ext4 -a -CO /dev/sda5
/dev/sda5 contains file system with errors, check forced.
[   10.803397] random: crng init done                     | 0.3%
/dev/sda5:
Extended attribute block 2740536 has reference account 6, should be 5.`

Comment: `/dev/sd5: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
fsck exited with status code 4
done.
Failture: File system check of the root filesystem failed
The root filesystem on /dev/sda5 requires a manual fsck
[   36.975860] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[   36.975860] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[   36.975860] usbhid: USB HID core driver



BusyBox v 1.22.1 (Ubuntu......`

Comment: .....and then cli runs
**If its a problem with a disk space, what can I delete to clean it?**
As I said before, I suppose that the problem is about disk space, I am not sure here.

ls command from root folder initial this
`dev   scripts   sbin   etc    run   bin   lib   proc
root  var       usr    lib64  conf  init  sys   tmp `

Comment: In linux cli I have limited capabilities of commands and I coudnt see all folders, for example /home or some folders inside others.
Using Disk Internals (Windows tool to get linux files), I can see everything. **I mean that files arent corrupted.**

Comment: df -H doesnt exist, I used df -P instead.

Input
`(initramfs) df -P`
Output
`Filesystem 1024-blocks Used Available Capacity MountedOn
udev 1935236 0 1935236 0% /dev
tmpfs 391752 0 391752 0% /run`

Comment: @MikeCiote the command is `df -h` Linux is case sensitive. `du -sh afolder/*` will tell you the size of your folders. I can't tell you what to delete. Try to find files that you have added and you don't need. If you have more details of your progress, update the question and keep it simple, organised and use formatting. It helps people understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks Katu! I supposed that problem is with a disk space, cause Linux didnt update an empty space, and after couple reloading, its was not enough of memory to even a copy simple file or launch an application. I have a decision - launch a `fsck` from live USB. Can you explain please, how can I do it, if when Im booting with a new USB, I am entering to a new system. I mean how can I check an installed system?

Comment: @MikeCiote This site works in a different way from other forums. If you have a different question, post a new one: https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask I would still check the disk space with the commands given and remove files until the system can boot again. Good luck!